# Descriptive error messages

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the following jQuery which does not give the most descriptive error messsages...

```
url: 'server_page.aspx',
type: 'POST',
data: { intID:$(this).attr("id"), strState:"1" },
error: function() { alert('Error'); },
success: function() {  }
```

How do I get more descriptive error messages if it is possible?

EDIT:

This is the full javascript:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() { 
        var that = this;

```
    if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'favorite_on_off.aspx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { strFavoriteID:$(that).attr("id"), strState:"1" },
            timeout: 1000,
            error: function(xhr, status, error)
            {
                alert("values: strFavoriteID: " + $(that).attr("id") + " strState: " + "1");
                alert('Error: ' + status + '\nError Text: ' + error);  
            },
            success: function() {  }
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'favorite_on_off.aspx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { strFavoriteID:$(that).attr("id"), strState:"0" },
            timeout: 1000,
            error: function(xhr, status, error)
            {
                alert("values: strFavoriteID: " + $(that).attr("id") + " strState: " + "0");
                alert('Error: ' + status + '\nError Text: ' + error);  
            },
            success: function() {  }
        });
    }
});
```

});

These are the error messages:

values: strFavoriteID: c:\folder\document.doc strState: 1

Error: error
Error Text: undefined

Comment: What are you looking for that you are not getting?  Also, since you are posting to an ASP.NET page, there are some POST variables that you need to have for a successful POST unless you have disabled the need for them on the ASP.NET page.

Comment: I'm just getting an error, instead of a database entry.

Comment: I've updated the original question to show the full script plus error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use all of the arguments passed to [the `error` callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), for example:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
  alert('Error: ' + status + '\nError Text: ' + error); 
},
```

Comment: This is giving me an alert message as follows "Error: error Error Text: undefined".

Comment: @oshirowanen - What do you get with `alert('Error: ' + status + '\nError Text: ' + error + '\nResponse Text: ' + xhr.responseText);`?  Also, this isn't the only debug method, using your console, or Firebug or Chrome's net panel are all good tools for seeing what's blowing up.

Comment: thanks, that gave me enough info to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument provided to the `error` callback is textStatus, which should contain a description of the error:

```
error: function(xhr, textStatus) { alert(textStatus); }
```

Note that you should probably not provide this information to your users.  Parse the message using Javascript and give them a nice friendly message explaining the error.

Comment: Using the `xhr` object, you will also be able to access the actual response returned from the server. `xhr.responseText` can give you the text of the .NET error page, your 404 page, or a 500 page. This can be very useful information.

Comment: @ lonesomeday, this is just giving me "error" in a alert box.

Comment: This isn't the main argument you want to use, as the actual error values are only null, "timeout", "error", "notmodified" and "parsererror"...it's better to include the third argument as well for much more detail in many cases.

Comment: @oshirowanen - try `alert(xhr.responseText)` or `$('#debug').html(xhr.responseText)`, with a `<div id="debug">...</div>` in your document.

Comment: I've updated the original question to show the full script plus error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I have this method:

```
function HandleAjaxError(request, status, error) {
    var ex = eval("(" + request.responseText + ")");

 $('body').addClass("ui-widget-overlay");
    alert(ex.Message);
    $('body').removeClass("ui-widget-overlay");
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.pathname + "/DoStuff",
    data: "{}",
    success: Success,
    error: HandleAjaxError
});
```

This way, I can gracefully handle the error message (and possibly the status code) on the ASP.NET side. I usually log the original error, then throw a custom/descriptive one for the client.